# Perform t-test per sub-group in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (df) where I want to perform t-test on observation for consequent groups. The number of groups is not constant.

**Dataframe:**

| key | group | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 1 | 5 |
| A1 | 1 | 7 |
| A1 | 1 | 6 |
| A1 | 1 | 4 |
| A1 | 2 | 4 |
| A1 | 2 | 2 |
| A1 | 2 | 8 |
| A1 | 2 | 4 |
| A1 | 3 | 5 |
| A1 | 3 | 4 |
| A1 | 3 | 8 |
| A1 | 3 | 4 |
| A2 | 1 | 4 |
| A2 | 1 | 2 |
| A2 | 1 | 4 |
| A2 | 1 | 8 |
| A2 | 2 | 9 |

**Objective:**

For each group for a key (lets say 'A1'), I want to perform t-test for group 1 vs. 2 and then 2 vs. 3, for column 'value'

**Note:**

1. For every key (eg: 'A1'), the sub-groups are not fixed (1 vs. 2, 2
   vs. 3, 3 vs. 4 etc.) but a minimum of two is always present.
2. There are more than 30 observation per groups

**Current Solution:**

My current solution is based on using a for-loop and performing t-test on every successive groups (I am using a pandas groupby so this applies for all 'keys'). and then storing the p-values as a new column in the original dataframe

```
groups = sorted(list(df['group'].unique()))
seq_of_groups = [groups[i: i + 2] for i in range(len(groups) - 2 + 1)]


for i in range(len(seq_of_groups)):
        df_one = df[df['group'] == seq_of_groups[i][0]]
        df_second = df[df['group'] == seq_of_groups[i][1]]
        test_val = stats.ttest_ind(df_one['value'], df_second['value'], equal_var=False)
```

**Expected Output:**

I find this solution not very clean, and i havent figured out how to add the results (p-values) as a new column in the original dataframe,

| key | group | value | result_p_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 1 | 5 | - |
| A1 | 1 | 7 | - |
| A1 | 1 | 6 | - |
| A1 | 1 | 4 | - |
| A1 | 2 | 4 | 0.04 |
| A1 | 2 | 2 | 0.04 |
| A1 | 2 | 8 | 0.04 |
| A1 | 2 | 4 | 0.04 |
| A1 | 3 | 5 | 0.001 |
| A1 | 3 | 4 | 0.001 |
| A1 | 3 | 8 | 0.001 |
| A1 | 3 | 4 | 0.001 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the toy dataframe you provided:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "key": ["A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1"],
        "group": [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3],
        "value": [5, 7, 6, 4, 4, 2, 8, 4, 5, 4, 8, 4],
    }
)
```

Here is one way to:

- simplify your code by using [pairwise](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise) from Python standard library's [itertool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#module-itertools) module
- and add results as a new column in the original dataframe

```py
from itertools import pairwise

for pair in pairwise(df["group"].unique()):  # (1, 2), (2, 3), ...
    df.loc[df["group"] == pair[1], "result_p_value"] = stats.ttest_ind(
        df.loc[df["group"] == pair[0], "value"],
        df.loc[df["group"] == pair[1], "value"],
        equal_var=False,
    )
```

Then:

```py
print(df)
# Fake p-values here

   key  group  value  result_p_value
0   A1      1      5             NaN
1   A1      1      7             NaN
2   A1      1      6             NaN
3   A1      1      4             NaN
4   A1      2      4           0.001
5   A1      2      2           0.001
6   A1      2      8           0.001
7   A1      2      4           0.001
8   A1      3      5           0.078
9   A1      3      4           0.078
10  A1      3      8           0.078
11  A1      3      4           0.078
```